# Mobile Site not giving correct Data - Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get product details from the following website.
[Baby Shampoo](http://m.target.com/p/johnson-s-gentle-care-gift-set/-/A-13197674#prodSlot=_1_1)
Specifically the TCIN:# and product details.
But this information is not showing up in the page when I parse it.

A simple line like:

```
spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class" : "list-value"})
```

is turning up no results, and when do I go even more basic to:

```
print(soup.prettify)
```

I see the page print out but none of the details are in the page. I am not seeing any iframes on the page, and can't figure out why the data is not showing.

I even attempted to adjust my headers in the request:

`headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev> (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Mobile Safari/<WebKit Rev>'}`

and also:

```
headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

but neither of these are changing the results. Any ideas what could be happening, and where this data could be located?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Do you see the desired information on page source? Dont do that using Insepct Element in browser, rather right click on page and click View Source and see whether the expected tags and attributes are there. I checked and cant find any tag with class "list-value". This happens when all the source is not sent in the original get request. To find all the network requests, use Network tab in Developer Console.

Comment: Vilas, when using all browsers I can see and inspect all elements I'm trying to get with my script.

Comment: Thats why I am trying to explain, browsers and Inspect Element displays html after aggregating the responses from all requests, whereas Page Source could be much smaller. "Right click on page and click View Source and see whether the expected tags and attributes are there"

Comment: Vikas, I see what you are saying now, and when viewing page source I don't see the element any more. So how do I go about coding for this? Do I have to use selenium vs Beautiful soup since, soup is not loading the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see all the Network Requests through Chrome Developer Options or Firefox Firebug, you can see all the http get and post requests made and then you have to find out which one contains the needed information. Make sure that you have Network toolbar enabled and Preserve Log checked before making the request in browser. In your case, the information is fetched by the GET request - http://tws.target.com/productservice/services/item_service/v1/by_itemid?id=13197674&callback=browseCallback

Comment: Vikas, thank you. So with some testing, would it be safe to assume that I can skip the initial link I posted and if I have the product ID# I can replace that # in the tws.target link and get information on other products as well?

Comment: It completely depends on the websites being scraped. Some websites send cookies in the initial request which need to be sent back in further requests. But for this site, it is fine. And you know do loads of testing bu changing ids and all and see what happens :)